# How to reduce parser process when running dbt on Airflow

Tags: airflow, dbt

I am running dbt version 1.0.4 on Airflow. My ETL pipeline is running fine.

But I notice that dbt takes a long time to parse files every time it run on Airflow. Some lines in the log:
`[2022-06-14 05:06:54,523] {subprocess.py:78} INFO - 05:06:54.506639 [debug] [MainThread]: Parsing macros/common/helpers/dropif.sql`

`[2022-06-14 05:06:55,826] {subprocess.py:78} INFO - 05:06:55.809703 [debug] [MainThread]: 1605: jinja rendering because of STATIC_PARSER flag. file: mart/domain_1/model_1.sql`

Since my project is quite big, it takes a looooong time to actual run the query.

So, is there any way for me to bypass the parsing?

Comment: To answer this question properly, we need to know the version of dbt you're running and the database or warehouse you're connecting to. Also, how large is your project and what is the total parse time? You may want to consult these docs as a starting point, and enable the new parser (v1+) and partial parsing. https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/parsing

Answer (score 0):

I add `--no-static-parser`. But I want to reduce more parsing time.